Flower API running with multiple aggregation servers
I want to use Flower for developing a distributed federated learning application, where instead of a single aggregator, there will be multiple servers for the aggregation.
I am wondering if it is possible to run multiple servers using Flower to decentralize the aggregation and how to do it?
